# Passing appended text box values back to Google App Script Side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script

I have figured out how to append text boxes and set class as autocomplete therefore setting default values as the dynamic list generated in an avaliableTag function on the google app script side. I need to get each appended text box value back to the google app script side so the end user can submit the data and a new row of data will be appended to the google sheet. Here is my html code

```
 <label for="units" style="font-size:125%;"><b>Number of items on Ticket</b></label>
      <input type="text" name="units" id="units">
      <!-- specified units by user-->

      <button id = 'numitems' onclick = "getUnits()">Add items </button>
      <!-- button that runs function to append appropriate # of boxes -->


      </div>
      <button id = 'submit' type = 'submit'name = "action">Submit </button>
```

Here is my google script code (left out doGet and HTML Service) these functions are what the user will submit to google sheet and the function that generates autocomplete options. Still need to get userInfo.MEDS

```
function userClicked(userInfo){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('someURL');
    var ws= ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1')
    var user = Session.getActiveUser();
    var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'CST', 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss')
  Logger.log(userInfo)
    ws.appendRow([user,userInfo.id,userInfo.ticket,userInfo.items,userInfo.MEDS,timestamp]);
  } 



function getAvailableTags() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("someId");
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("someSheet");
  var data= s.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
  var headers = 1;
  var tagColumn = 0; 

  var availableTags = [];
  for (var row=headers; row < data.length; row++) {
    availableTags.push(data[row][tagColumn]);
  }

  return( availableTags );
}
```

and finally here is the js/jquery side

```
var x=1
function appendRow()
{
   var d = document.getElementById('left-col');
   d.innerHTML += "<input type='text'class = 'autocomplete' id='tst"+ x++ +"'><br >";
}
function getUnits() {
    var units = $("#units").val();
    x=1
    for (var count = 1; count < units; count++) {
        $("<input type='text'class = 'autocomplete' id='tst"+ x++ +"'><br >").appendTo("#left-col");
    }
   var mednum = 0
    $("#left-col").append("<input type='text'class = 'autocomplete' id='tst"+ x++ +"'>")
    ;
}

$(function() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildTagList)
      .getAvailableTags();
});

function buildTagList(availableTags) {
  $( ".autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
}
$('#submit').on('click', function (){
   $('.autocomplete').each(function() {
      var med =  $(this).val();
      console.log(med);
   });
});
 window.onload=function(){  
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click',buttonClick);

function buttonClick() {
var userInfo = {};
userInfo.Id = document.getElementById('ptid').value
userInfo.ticket = document.getElementById('ticket').value
userInfo.items = document.getElementById('items').value

}}
```

I need something that will take value of each appended box and let me store it in the userInfo object so it can be passed back to the gs side

Comment: In your case, the value of `userInfo` can be sent to `userClicked` of Google Apps Script by putting `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(doSomething).userClicked(userInfo);` to the last line of `buttonClick()`. But unfortunately, in your script you provided, `document.getElementById('ptid')`, `document.getElementById('ticket')` and `document.getElementById('items')` are null. So I cannot understand whether this is what you want. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `google.script.run` to run a function in code.gs side and send the form object [1]. Also, you should prevent the default behavior for when the form is submitted:

```
function buttonClick() {
    var userInfo = {};
    userInfo.Id = document.getElementById('ptid').value
    userInfo.ticket = document.getElementById('ticket').value
    userInfo.items = document.getElementById('items').value
    google.script.run.userClicked(userInfo)
}

$("#formID").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms